# Tap on a cell affects other cell too

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch, reusability

I'm trying to build a custom cell with different button inside, but when I tap "follow button" in on cell and color this button it seems that other follow button get a color too...Also if I scroll up and down my tableView other button randomly get color...I'm still learning how to use custom cell...

Here there is my custom cell

```
class customCell: UITableViewCell
{
    @IBOutlet weak var follow: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var comment: UIButton?
    @IBOutlet var share: UIButton? 
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{


 let cellPost = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! customCell

    cellPost.tag = Array(postToPrint.keys)[indexPath.row]

    cellPost.follow?.tag = Array(postToPrint.keys)[indexPath.row]
    cellPost.follow?.addTarget(self, action: "follow:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    return cellaPost
    }
}
```

Here there is my function follow

```
 func follow(sender: UIButton)
{
    let postSelected = sender.tag
    // In order to get indexPath from int values
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: postSelected, inSection: 1)
    let cell = table.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! customCell
    cell.follow.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: UIControlState)
    idPostClicked = postSelected
    sendHttpRequest(postClicked : idPostClicked)

}
```

I'm giving as tag to every cell my dictionary keys. Later I want to take cell.tag and send it as parameter in sendHttpRequest method. If I put my button function inside my customCell I want to get the cell in which there is my followButton so I can send a request with cell.tag.
However text get colored in other cell when I click only one...:/

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I feel like you are going about this in the wrong way. I would rather move the `func follow` into the cell itself. There's no reason for the tableView to handle this logic since it's the cell who'd like to change elements it can access on its own. Also, if you move the logic into the cell then you won't need `tags` or add targets etc.

```
class customCell: UITableViewCell
{
    @IBOutlet weak var follow: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var comment: UIButton?
    @IBOutlet var share: UIButton? 

    // Connect the follow button to this function as an action
    @IBAction followPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        follow.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellPost = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! customCell
    return cellaPost
}
```

This should do the trick, I believe.

### Edit

Added some missing code for `UIControlState` for the button. If this doesn't work could you upload a sample project? Hard to pinpoint what you are trying to do with only this piece of code.

Comment: how can I get the cell where the button clicked is in ? I need to send a request Htttp passing as parameter post followed

Comment: Added an edit. Think I'll have to see more code depending on how you want to do the HTTP request.